# Same root category, different category structure based on store views

Tags: category, catalog

I have 2 store views sharing the same root category.

Is it possible to change the category structure based on store view?

If I drag the category on a store view it makes the change in the other store view.

Maybe there is a setting that I don't know.

To be clearer, I need a sub-category to have different parents based on store view, without duplicating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible by default without duplicating the sub category and setting it to display only on the Store View that you want it to display on.  Note this will also effect the URL path to the products in the sub categories.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible without customization.  I think you just need to maintain two trees.   There are extensions out there to duplicate categories, so that could make it a little easier.

Also you could use some separate menu extension altogether that let's you arrange by category ids per store view.  Many mega menu extensions have their own organization UI like this

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't allow to change the categories at store view at the same level as products.

The product-category relation is not on storeview level.